Get a specific text from an output value
I'm trying to get a value from an output sample below using a custom app that I ran on PowerShell.
The output looks like this:
---
releaseId: 1124503
releaseName: "Release 3"
releaseDescription: ""
suspended: false

The text I need to get is the releaseId value (1124503). Note that this value changes every time I run the app.
Trying the:
| Select-Object -ExpandProperty releaseId

doesn't work. Any tips?

How exactly did you get this output? You may have to parse it. ‍♂️

That looks like YAML so maybe find a tool for working with that.

@jonrsharpe Im working on it via Jenkins.

Might be able to use Select-String to get the digits after releaseId:
$output | Select-String 'releaseId:\s*(?<digits>[0-9]+)' -List |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Matches[0].Groups['digits'].Value }

Considering the output is from a file, the you can also use the cmdlet to read its content:
Select-String -Path path\to\thefile -Pattern 'releaseId:\s*(?<digits>[0-9]+)' -List |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Matches[0].Groups['digits'].Value }

See https://regex101.com/r/28RwwS/1 for regex details.

@kenomote Select-String -Path path\to\thefile ? it's in my answer

I updated my post with another output, sorry about that.

completely different from the initial question @kenomote. That should be asked in a new question instead of adding follow up questions to this one. I'm rolling back your update.

Hi again, I tried to use the regex with a different output format but I cant capture the "scanId", is it because there is a space on the initials?
[https://regex101.com/r/IRxPmX/1]
